# Trigger executa caso valor de uma coluna seja 'Banco de Dados I'

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, trigger

Crie um gatilho que matricule automaticamente um aluno
em “Laboratorio de BD I” assim que este for matriculado em
“Banco de dados I”.

```
    use Universidade;

insert into Realiza_matricula (RGAacad, Nomedisc) values(20179474911, 'Banco de Dados I');

Delimiter $$
create trigger matricula
after insert on Realiza_matricula
for each row
    BEGIN
        IF (select * From Realiza_matricula Where Nomedisc = 'Banco de Dados I') THEN
            insert into Realiza_matricula values (NEW.RGAacad, 'Laboratorio de BD I', OLD.Date);
        end if;
    END $$
Delimiter;
```

Comment: Não seria mais prático apenas verificar se NEW.Nomedisc  é 'Banco de dados I' e neste caso inserir a disciplina 'Laboratorio de BD I', sem necessidade de fazer a consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Usa o `EXISTS` na frente do `if`, "Se existir rows...". Obs: Use o `NOT EXISTS` para quando não retornar rows:

```
 IF EXISTS(select * From Realiza_matricula Where Nomedisc = 'Banco de Dados I') THEN
            insert into Realiza_matricula values (NEW.RGAacad, 'Laboratorio de BD I', OLD.Date);
        end if;
```